# Doing túró at home

Tags: cheese-making, hungarian-cuisine

Is there a way to do túró (a Hungarian quark cheese/curd with a very specific taste) at home? I miss that specific taste and I've not found a cheese in Italy that approximate it (not even local quark cheese that is very different).

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it, we are also doing it at home.
In my interpretation there are two kind of túró. One is created from cow milk, this one tastes sweet. The another is created from sheep cheese, and this one is a bit spicy. The second one is traditional food of székely's.  In which one you are interrested?

**Update.**

1. The sweet turó from cow milk (this one for túró rudi and for túrósgombóc).

- You have to let the milk for 2-3 days in a warm area, to get it slept.
- After that you have to remove the stuff from the top of it.
- Then put the rest to a slow fire and warm it a bit, not too much. (Do not stir it.)
- Then you filter the content from the water with a gauze or something similar.
- Done.

2. Spicy Túró (for túróscsúsza)

For this one you have to get sheep cheese.

- You have to cut the cheese to small cubes (1-2cm).
- Then put it into very salty water for a few hours.
- Then you have to blend it with meat grinder (A blender would make it too small).
- Done.

Hope you will make it very tasty:) Good luck.

Comment: Both kind I presume, as I would to cook túrósgombóc, túrós csusza and trying to do home-made Túró Rudi...

Comment: Some clarification needed:
- Should I leave the milk outside the fridge in an opened or closed container? Have I to use whole milk? Will I get aludttej?
- Which kind of sheep cheese have I to use?

Comment: Yes you should get aludttej first. I dont know how many sheep cheese types exists. We are doing from fresh, few weeks old sheep cheese.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be two schools of thought on making túró: one method just drains the whey from "slept milk" (aludttej), while another cooks the sour milk (on very low heat) first, then drains it. If you choose the cooked method, avoid stirring - you want to give the proteins a chance to coagulate.

In either case, the trick tends to be finding milk that will sleep properly, rather than becoming bitter unpalatable crud. If you can't find raw milk, or at least non-homogenized (but pasteurized) milk, you can try helping things along with an inoculation of yogurt/buttermilk, or a little bit of lemon juice/vinegar.

You can make túró with whatever fat-content you like: skim milk will curdle just as well as whole milk. In fact, most recipes call for removing the cream from the top of the aludttej before proceeding to the cooking/draining.

(I hear you about the so-called local equivalent -- "quark cheese", "cottage cheese" -- being nothing at all like the real thing. I don't know about Italy, but the closest I've found to túró here on the east coast of the US is actually something called "farmer's cheese". Unfortunately, it's a pretty localized thing - I never even heard of it while growing up in California.)