# How to make a Hungarian Túró Rudi at home?

Tags: cheese, hungarian-cuisine

I want to make some Túró Rudi for a Hungarian friend. Túró Rudi is a chocolate sweet available to buy in Hungary, and vast numbers are sold every year. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BAr%C3%B3_Rudi

The outside is easy, it's just chocolate. The tricky part is the inside, which has the consistency of the inside of a Bounty (coconut) bar for those that know it. the centre is white firm and sweet, but in the Túró Rudi it is made with cottage cheese (Túró) and sugar, but how can I make a firm, sugary centre out of cottage cheese? I've had them in a restaurant so they can certainly be made in a kitchen.

I've searched and searched for a recipe, but I cannot find one. I'm happy to experiment, and any help is welcome.

Comment: The first problem is that while yes, túró is often translated as "cottage cheese", the two cheeses are actually not at all alike. I mean, not even remotely, not in texture, not in taste, not in any way that matters. A closer American equivalent (available on the east coast, but very hard to find on the west) is farmer cheese, but even that isn't quite right.

Comment: Hi Marti, thank you so much for clarifying that. I Googled and it seems that it's called Quark Cheese in many places, including here in the UK. http://www.ocado.com/webshop/product/Golden-Acre-Virtually-Fat-Free-Quark/11504011?from=search&tags&param=quark&parentContainer=SEARCHquark_SHELFVIEW    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_cheese

Comment: Your search skills leave a lot to be desired, it would seem: http://m.mindmegette.hu/recept/4280. Google can translate it for you.

Comment: Many thanks. Google Translate makes a mess of the translation (it suggests I need to add venison to the mixture :) ) but I can ask a friend to translate it. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I will select it.

Comment: In reviewing whether this question should be closed as off topic, I consider it more like recreating a specific restaurant recipe, and less as a generic recipe request--so I think it can stay open.

Comment: see also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/doing-t%C3%BAr%C3%B3-at-home

Comment: I'm a bit late, but I think the reason Google was stumbling on the mindmegette recipe was because the recipe calls for using a "venison rib mold", which is basically a [ribbed baking dish](http://www.brillcatering.com/pix/2802/n_17716.jpg). Also, the recipe as posted contains a few misspellings and other grammatical errors, leading to even more confusion on the poor machine translator's part.

Answer (score 5):

I spent quite a bit of time working on a variety of recipes for this. In all honesty, none are particularly close to the "real thing" but the results can taste pretty good and are reminiscent of the actual product.

The main challenge is in buying authentic túró. After a lot of work, I've confirmed that there's no standard, easily available equivalent in the UK. British quark, an easily available curd, is very different to túró. British cottage cheese is really nothing like túró. So if you're in the UK and want to make anything with túró, you'll need to compromise on taste, or buy some túró from a Hungarian or Eastern/Central European provider. Alternatively you could make your own by acquiring the curd from soured milk.

The recipe I used with the best results was simple. Mix the túró with a little sour cream and some fine sugar to sweeten it to your taste. Stir in some liquid (melted) gelatine. Pour the mixture into moulds (I used a small ice cube tray) and freeze it. When frozen hard, quickly dip each in chocolate and put them in the fridge.

The texture is jelly-like, which is very different to a real túró rudi (which is firm and slightly crystalline), but it tastes pretty good.

Comment: [This site](http://www.hunglish.org/articles/hungarian-turo-rudi) suggests that "cream cheese" (or Neufchatel perhaps) is a possibility.

Comment: That does make sense. Since last posting I went to the Hungarian shop in Manor House in North London ("Paprika Store") and bought some real túró and I've also been to Hungary again and tasted it in a few dishes, and it does taste a lot more like soft cheese than cottage cheese or quark. To my tongue it tastes more like ricotta or Philadelphia soft cheese than cottage cheese or quark. I think our Hungarian friends have left a false trail by translating it as cottage cheese :-)

Comment: I dunno, I don't think cream cheese tastes anything like túró (and of course the texture is completely different)...

Answer (score 2):

In the US you can use ricotta cheese.

for a 32. oz. tub, put in 
2 tbs sour cream, 
1 tbs. melted butter, 
1/2 tsp. fresh lemon zest (you can leave it out)
1 tbs sugar
little unflavored gelatin to help stay in shape
As Hungarian i can tell you, this is close enough :)

Sweet Ricotta Cheese Balls (Hungarian Túrógombóc, Turogomboc) is an other hit for Hungarians, really easy to make them:
http://allrecipes.com/personalrecipe/63603144/sweet-ricotta-cheese-balls-hungarian-turogomboc-turogomboc/detail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own cheese
4 liter milk give you 500gr soft cheese
Worm up the milk 7 min. Thermo meter is your index finger
When hot finger cannot stand but not boil, 
Put a cup of vinegar in and stir until You see the cheese 
Filter through a cloth and have 500gr chemical free cheese 
10 minits

Answer (score 0):

I am Hungarian, and the "close enough" evaluation of the recipe is a bit generous. The flavor is a bit off, and the texture is definitely off. Mine was too soft and crumbly even out of the fridge, definitely when defrosted. (I also need to work on my skills to cover it with chocolate, that part was a complete disaster :).
But what I came here to write - I will try it next time with Queso Fresco instead of Ricotta. I make the Cheese Balls referenced above with it, and it turns out exactly like the ones at home.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps a combination of cottage and cream cheese put into an ice tube mold and allowed time to set a bit.