# What is dry cottage cheese?

Tags: cheese

My grandmother's recipe for cheese filling for kolacky calls for dry cottage cheese.  What is that and where might I get some?

Comment: Where are you from? It might help in giving buying advice.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no, it's not at all feta like. Judging from the recipe name and the OP's name, we're dealing with a recipe from Eastern Europe, so the cheese will be of the tvorog family (the description "dry cottage cheese" is also the best way to name this cheese, which seems to be unknown in English speaking countries and so has no recognizable name). It's very different from feta both in texture and taste.

Comment: I am of two minds whether to close this as a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29014/how-to-make-a-hungarian-t%C3%BAr%C3%B3-rudi-at-home. It seems to be the same problem, pertaining to a cheese of the same family. I'll leave the community votes to decide whether to keep this question open too, or whether they are similar enough to be considered duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Dry cottage cheese is called Farmer's Cheese.  The curds and whey are separated, and the curds are pressed.  My Russian grandmother used Farmer's Cheese as a filling for blintzes.